# Unsupported WFS request in MapServer at Insert and Update

Tags: wfs, mapserver, sql-server

I'm created a WFS with MapServer (ms4w) and SQL Server DB. The wfs:GetFeature works fine. But I cann't get the wfs:insert/wfs:update to work, they return:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.1.0" language="en-US" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
      <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidRequest" locator="request">
        <ows:ExceptionText>msWFSParseRequest(): WFS server error. Unsupported WFS request.</ows:ExceptionText>
      </ows:Exception>
    </ows:ExceptionReport>
```

My table:

```
    CREATE TABLE Plots
    (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Title VARCHAR(30),
    Plot GEOMETRY
    )
```

and created a map file:

```
    MAP
      NAME           "crop"
      STATUS         ON
      CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:\ms4w\proj\nad"
      WEB
        IMAGEPATH "c:\ms4w\tmp\ms_tmp"
        IMAGEURL "/ms_tmp/"
        METADATA
          "wfs_title"            "Crop plots" ## REQUIRED
          "wfs_onlineresource"   "http://localhost/mapserver/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/crop/crop.map&" ## Recommended
          "wfs_abstract"         "Crop plots" ## Recommended
          "wfs_enable_request"   "*"  # necessary
          "wfs_namespace_uri"    "http://www.cropvision.com"
          "wfs_namespace_prefix" "crop"
        END
      END
      PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:28992"
      END

      LAYER
        NAME         "plots"
        STATUS       ON
        TYPE         POLYGON
        METADATA
          "wfs_title"           "Plots"
          "gml_include_items"   "all"
          "wfs_enable_request"  "*"
          "gml_geometries"      "plot"
          "gml_plot_type"       "multipolygon"
          "gml_featureid"       "Title"
        END

        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:28992"
        END
        PROCESSING 'CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER'
        CONNECTIONTYPE PLUGIN
        PLUGIN "C:\ms4w\Apache\specialplugins\msplugin_mssql2008.dll"
        CONNECTION "server=myServer;database=myDB;uid=myUID;pwd=myPWD"
        DATA "Plot FROM dbo.Plots USING UNIQUE id"
     END
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just nearsighted. The problem is that mapserver realy doesn't support WFS-T. http://mapserver.org/ogc/wfs_server.html#to-do-items-and-known-limitations